# How to hide the left pane in JS grid gantt chart in sharepoint

Tags: gantt-view

I am trying to create a custom gant chart control in sharepoint by using JS Grid control. I am following this tutorial: [How to: Create a Gantt Chart Using the JS Grid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407962(v=office.14).aspx)

> 1) How can I hide left pane in the JSGrid Gantt chart view

The example that I am following is getting the data from the columns on the left.

**Edit:**

First question has been answered by iOnline247

> 2) How can I expand the right pane to 100%
>
> 3) How can I reposition the bars created in the gantt view?

[image]

Comment: do you have a picture?

Comment: I just added an image. I have highlighted the columns in yellow. That's what I would like to hide/remove and display the gantt view in expended mode

Comment: No one has experience with JS Grid and gantt chart?

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS, I've been able to hide the left pane.

```
div[id$='JSGrid_leftpane'] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i will give it a try and get to you soon.

Comment: Hi iOnline247, I used this id 'grid_leftpane' and it worked. I don't know what is the difference with the id you gave above.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: since you are the only one till now to know more about JS grid, I have two questions for you:


1) how to expand the right pane all other divs inside it?
2) how can I reposition bars that are created in the gantt view?

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I've only briefly fiddled with this, so I'm not real sure. The scroll bars seem to break if you remove stuff using CSS.  You may want to fiddle around there and come up with something.

I'm not sure how to answer #3. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with that.